# What does DefaultPromptEnableTiming show in posh-git prompt?

Tags: powershell, posh-git

There is a boolean variable called DefaultPromptEnableTiming in posh-git.
When set to true, there is a number at the end of the promt.

Any suggestion gratefully received. Thanks in advance.